# What way is better for init class property with default value when the create the instance of class

Tags: c#, oop, instance

I have the following simple class:

```
public class SimpleClass{
    public int SimpleProperty {get; set;}

    public SimpleClass(){

    }
}
```

I need to init the property SimpleProperty by default value when I create the instance of SimpleClass.
What the bast way doing this?

1. Create the parameter in constructor and pass the default value when the create the instance of Simple Class:

   ```
   public class SimpleClass{
       public int SimpleProperty {get; set;}

       public SimpleClass(int simpleProperty){
           SimpleProperty = simpleProperty;
       }
   }
   ```
2. or init the property in default constructor:

   ```
   public class SimpleClass{

       public int SimpleProperty {get; set;}

       public SimpleClass(){
           SimpleProperty = 0; //the example of default value
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: in c# 6 you can do `public int SimpleProperty {get; set;} = -1;`  to default-initialize properties

Comment: "Best"? That's impossible to say because you're not giving us the criteria against which you would judge two solutions. The two examples you give *do different things*, you can't pick and choose unless you want to do different things.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen please explain me what different things?

Comment: Well, one requires the caller to provide the "default value", the other doesn't, it forces the caller to use object initialization syntax instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it very depends on what project you're working with.

If it is big enterprise project, and your property is of some object type (which make your class to depend on some other object) the first option would be much more preferable as it allows to use IoC containers, and frameworks and it also simplifies the way of how unit tests can be written as it's simple to pass a mock value inside of ctor and not so simple, if ctor is not accepting arguments.

With simple types, like `int` or in a simple pet project however it doesn't really matter and is up to you to decide. Don't forget, that you can use *optional* parameters for ctor :

```
public SimpleClass(int simpleProperty = 15)
{
    SimpleProperty = simpleProperty;
}
```

Comment: OP asks about default-values. Dependencies are a completely different thing and don´t have a default-value at all (however their properties might have).

Comment: It depends on how is this value used later not to mention that OP could be confusing this things.

Comment: You mix things when you bring dependencies in, as dependencies (any kind of reference-type) can´t have a default-value other then `null`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thank you, I've updated my answer, explaining that

Comment: @Fabjan thank you for your answer. Your answer is helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

These are two different approaches. If you have a default-value you can usually *omit* setting a value for this property. Thus you should initialize the default-value within the constructor.

```
var a new SimpleClass();
```

Now `a` has the default-value you provided within the constructor.

Having a signature that *expects* an argument on the other hand *forces* the user to provide a value. This means there is no default-value at all and you can´t omit the value.

```
var a = SimpleClass();  // this won´t compile
```

By the way you forgot about the third approach: optional arguments:

```
SimpleClass(int value = -1)
{
    SimpleProperty = value;
}
```

Now you can use it as my first approach

```
var a = new SomeSimpleClass()
```

or

```
var a = new SimpleClass(1)
```

From C#6 onwards things are a bit easier as you can give your property a default-value:

```
int SimpleProperty { get; set; } = -1;
```

Anyway if your default-value is just zero you can omit it completely as zero is the default-value anyway for `int`.

Comment: thak you for your approach

Answer (score 1):

Consider also making the class immutable:

```
public class SimpleClass
{
    // getter only, no setter
    public int SimpleProperty { get; }

    public SimpleClass(int simpleProperty)
    {
        // allowed in C#6+
        SimpleProperty = simpleProperty;
    }
}
```

If your properties are writable (i.e. the class is mutable), no constructor overload will really prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: What does this have to do with a default-value?

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Other answers cover optional parameters, so I just wanted to add on that. Explicit value, injected through the constructor, with no other way to write `SimpleProperty` is in my opinion more important that other considerations. OP's snippets do two completely different things, so it's not completely clear what s/he means by the default value. I hope my answer is at least somewhat useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple constructors. So you can actually use both.

So, if the user doesn't provide a value, then set it to 0 by default.